# How to Authlib OAuth for Google Sign In in headless infrastructure (Vue JS and FastAPI)? Error: blocked by CORS policy

Tags: vue.js, cors, fastapi, google-signin, authlib

I have a headless infrastructure of Vue JS (front end) and FastAPI (back end).

I try to create login system using Authlib by using this tutorial:
[Authlib Google Login Tutorial for FastAPI](https://blog.authlib.org/2020/fastapi-google-login)

I is succeeded if I try to sign in via the back end (API) URL, for example :

```
https://apilink/login
```

It will took me to the google sign in page.

However, since I use Vue JS as a front end, I need to able to login the user when visiting:

```
https://frontendlink/login
```

But, there is an error when I try to:

```
axios.get(https://apilink/login)
```

The error is:

> login:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth....' (redirected from 'https://apilink/login') from origin 'https://frontendlink' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Please help me how to implement the good practice of authlib using headless infrastructure like this. thank you

Comment: You can't use OAuth with just a get request in the background, the browser has to navigate there. The easiest would probably be to do a redirect from your frontend page `https://frontendlink/login` to your backend URL `https://apilink/login`, and then make sure to redirect back to your frontend when oauth is done.